# Customising geom_point parameters in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to customise stroke thickness and corner style in ggplot.  Mapping a variable to the area of squares, and I find that corner rounding is causing smaller squares become circular.  Does ggplot have this functionality, or is there maybe a different way of plotting squares to the `pch=22` method?

Many thanks in advance.

```
t <- data.frame(x=rep(c(1:5),5)/5, y=rep(c(1:5),each=5)/5, s=round(seq(1,10,length.out=25)))
t
p <- ggplot(data=t, aes(x=x,y=y))

p + geom_point(aes(size=s), pch=22, fill=NA, col='black') +
  scale_area(range = c(0, 2))

# options e.g. linejoin = "mitre", lineend = "butt" don't work
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unresolved and withdrawn (lack of response).